# Want to Extract name and value from Response

Tags: jmeter, extract, jmeter-plugins

Want to Extract name and value from Response.

```
input type="hidden" name="IbkVkZ7Zhk8=" value="B7DDe0z5xEGnlxKhPTQccoYGyA3Xk3lwHPDfzH6kGoQGHnVt6QHYI93OjGmtaEjr"
```

I am using Regular expression Extractor as Below :

1.tokenName

```
input type="hidden" name="(.+?)=" value=""
```

2.tokenValue

```
input type="hidden" name="${tokenName}" value="(.+?)"
```

but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Give in a sample of your data and the regex that you have used so far.

Comment: i have updated Question Please take a look ..thanks

Comment: The regex seems fine, syntax-wise, try to check in with some other setting for the Regular Expression Extractor.

Comment: name and value both are different for each user so , it seems like unable to get value of  **tokenName** using value=" " .

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use two different expressions, use a single regex to extract both, like `input type="hidden" name="(.+?)=" value="(.+?)"` and the regex should give you two different matches, the first one is the tokenName and the second is the tokenValue.

Comment: thanks for reply,
how can i get both value from same regex. 
i mean can you please tell me how to specify **Reference Name** in Regex .
i tried something like :  tokenName,tokenValue  but it gives me error.

Comment: @cyber_rookie i got it from 
[http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html]
thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following Regular Expression Extractor configuration:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `test`
- Regular Expression: `input type="hidden" name="(.+?)" value="(.+?)"`
- Template: `$1$`

This will generate 2 match groups and you will be able to address

- "name" as `${test_g1}`
- "value" as `${test_g2}`

[image: Regex Tester]

You can use [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) in combination with [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to visualize Regular Expression Extractor matches results.

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for more tips.